# Where clause on colon-separated list in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-execution-plan

Looking for some help with an Oracle SQL query

I have 2 tables

First is `USERS`:

```
User Name | User Type
----------------------
JOHN | OFFICE
BOB  | REMOTE
PAUL | OFFICE
LISA | REMOTE
```

I then have a `Reports` table with a list of reports along with a colon delimited access list

```
REPORT NAME | ACCESS_LIST
---------------------------
REPORT_1  |  OFFICE:REMOTE
REPORT_2  |  OFFICE
REPORT_3  |  REMOTE
```

If I'm logged in as JOHN who is OFFICE user then the query should return

```
REPORT NAME
--------------
REPORT_1
REPORT_2
```

I've triad various suggestions around where clauses using comma separated strings but none have been able to do what I'm looking for

1 that did work is

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (select regexp_substr(ACCESS_LIST,'[^:]+', 1, level) as USERTYPE,ID 
    FROM DF_DOC_STORE
    connect by regexp_substr(ACCESS_LIST, '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null) 
WHERE USERTYPE = 'OFFICE'
```

But when I add in the where clause the query goes from taking less than a second to run to taking over 1 minute; there are only 10 rows in the DF_DOC_STORE table so I really don't understand what the issue is with my query, but clearly I'm doing something wrong

The explain plan for the query without the where clause is

```
Plan 
  SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS Cost: 3  Bytes: 26  Cardinality: 2             
  3 VIEW A14730. Cost: 3  Bytes: 26  Cardinality: 2  
  2 CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING 
  1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE A14730.DF_DOC_STORE  Cost: 3  Bytes: 190  Cardinality: 2
```

When I add in the where clause it jumps to this

```
Plan 
 SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS Cost: 3  Bytes: 4,030  Cardinality: 2 
 3 VIEW A14730. Cost: 3  Bytes: 4,030  Cardinality: 2               
 2 CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING                 
 1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE A14730.DF_DOC_STORE Cost: 3  Bytes: 190  Cardinality: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest just try using `like`.  Here is the idea:

```
select *
form df_doc_store
where ':' || access_list || ':' like '%:' || 'OFFICE'  || ':';
```

This assumes that you know that the current user has the type of `'OFFICE'`.

I should add that comma or colon delimited lists are a very poor way of storing such information.  The normal way in a relational database is to use a junction table, although Oracle also supports nested tables for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much.... it worked perfectly i can now get to bed & not spend all night worrying about it...   I agree about having a mapping table, the value gets set at the moment via a shuttle list in APEX, i've not had time to redesign the document upload for to manage the access lists a bit better.

Comment: APEX has an API function apex_string.apex_split(p_str, p_sep, p_limit) that returns a type apex_t_varchar2; see https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEAPI/SPLIT-Function-Signature-1.htm#AEAPI-GUID-3BE7FF37-E54F-4503-91B8-94F374E243E6 The type apex_t_varchar2 is defined as a  WWV_FLOW_T_VARCHAR2 TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767)